# How to trim/remove "\n" in a string in python

Tags: python

I have query.I am new to Python

Lets say I have a file `in.txt`. Inside this file I have some name like below.

```
Sunday

Monday

Tuesday
.
.
```

I want to put them into a list, I am doing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
with open("in.txt") as f:
lines = f.readlines()
lines = [l for l in lines]
print (lines);
```

The output is:

```
['Sunday\n', 'Monday\n', 'Tuesday\n']
```

I want to print it like:

```
['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday']
```

how will I remove `\n`

Any suggestion will great help,  I tried `rstrip()` it didn't work.

Comment: How did you try to use `rstrip()` ?

Comment: use strip('\n').

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
lines = [l.strip() for l in lines]
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response ..

Answer (score 1):

It should work with `rstrip()` or even `strip()`, like this:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

lines = [l.rstrip() for l in lines]
print (lines)
```

Or, more concisely:

```
with open("in.txt") as f: 
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response ..

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension with `rstrip`:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    lines = [i.rstrip() for i in f]
print(lines)
```

Output:

```
['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday']
```

Comment: Don't need the `.readlines()` there... that'll read the entire file first... just loop line-by-line using just `f` instead... so just something like lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]` is fine.

Comment: @JonClements Good point, edited mine.

Comment: Thanks for quick response ..